# As groups are to group-algebras, group-algebras are to what?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given a group $G$ with elements $g_n$, which act under group multiplication $\times$ , one can introduce a new operator $+$, and form linear combinations  $\sum\limits_n \alpha_n g_n\subset \mathbb{A}$ where $\forall_n\alpha_n\subset \mathbb{R}$ for example. 
This is the "group algebra" which is the field extension of the real numbers with the group elements $\mathbb{A}=\mathbb{R}[G]$.

So we have gone from groups to algebras by adding a binary operator. (Although it required already having an algebra called the real numbers).

Are there any structures above that with a third operator, e.g. $\odot$? e.g. if $A_1$ and $A_2$ where members of the algebra then $A_1 \odot A_2$ would be a member this meta-structure? i.e. some kind of extension where the elements aren't group elements but elements of an algebra? (The difficulty is that the group might have $N$ members but then the algebra has $\mathbb{R}^N$ members.)

Comment: There are arbitrarily many structures with three operations. For instance, on an associative algebra (which is also an additive group under $+$) one can always define a Lie bracket setting $[a,b]=ab-ba$.

Comment: @Javi Yes but specifically taking two elements of an algebra and combining them into something that is not an element of the algebra.

Comment: ... are to representation theory of groups.